# How to set auctions according to their dates and current status?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

We want to set auctions according to their current status means currently running auctions should be shown in current auctions and future auctions will be categorised in upcoming auction category and outdated auctions should move to past auctions automatically, we dont need to categories them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a proper column in DB, like 'status' with value, f.ex. 1 => upcoming, 0 => active, -1 => closed, for each auction.

Then you can make easy check based on that and display cases in proper places.